# ReadLine and hard coded data produce different results

Tags: vb.net

I'm experimenting with writing an FTP client in Visual Basic. I want to get a working CLI. But I'm stumped at exactly why changing one line in my code causes a problem.

```
Dim ftpTcpClient As TcpClient = New TcpClient(IP, 21)
Dim RS As NetworkStream

RS = ftpTcpClient.GetStream

intRetBytesLen = ftpTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize
ReDim bteRetBytes(intRetBytesLen)
RS.Read(bteRetBytes, 0, intRetBytesLen)
strRetMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bteRetBytes)
Console.Write(strRetMsg)
Console.Write(vbCrLf)

strCmd = "USER " & user & vbCrLf

bteSendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strCmd)
RS.Write(bteSendBytes, 0, bteSendBytes.Length)
Console.Write(strCmd & vbCrLf)
```

The line in question is when I define strCmd. If I hard code in the User and pass, I can log-in successfully to the FTP server.

However, If I replace it with

```
strCmd = Console.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
```

I get an invalid user/password error. I have tried the code without adding on the CrLf as well, because I thought perhaps ReadLine automatically added one of these? Am I right here, and that would be the reason it breaks my code?

PS: I'm aware that the code I have is not complete for a proper implementation of FTP but right now I just want to understand why the code breaks.

Thank you.

Comment: Try two thing, have this in your code: strCmd = "USER " & user & vbCrLf. Then have this right after: Dim strCmd2 = Console.ReadLine() & vbCrLf. Then compare the two strings and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code

```
strCmd = "USER " & user & vbCrLf
```

Is not the same as

```
strCmd = Console.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
```

Probably because you forgot your prefix "USER ".  Try this instead:

```
strCmd = "USER " & Console.ReadLine() & vbCrLf
```